# My index match formula is returning #N/A and I cannot figure out why?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use an index match formula to return a value based on two values. However, it is returning #n/a. I have created a simple table with one row and 3 coloumns as a test to try and figure out what is going wrong. Below is a simple table I made for this purpose. I want to return column L based on the criteria from columns J and K.

```
 J  K   L
123 4   7
```

Here is the formula I have used.

```
=INDEX(L3,MATCH(1,(M8=J3)*(N8=K3),0))
```

I also used ctrl-shft-enter to run the formula but it is giving me an NA value. When I use an index match to return a value based on only one criteria, the formuala works and it returns a 7 but when I try for multiple criteria, the formula fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: The match statement works on ranges and the ranges should be an absolute references (the $ in the sample formula) so that they don't change.  You are feeding it a single cell as input.  It should generally look something like:  MATCH(1,(M8=$J$1:$J$100)*(N8=$K$1:$K$100))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is *Concatenate* the columns of interest then do the match. Try:

```
=INDEX(L3,MATCH(M8&N8,J3:J6&K3:K6,0))
```

This should be entered as *array formula* using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>.
What the formula does is:

1. Concatenate the values being searched in memory.

   ```
   =INDEX(L3,MATCH(123&4,J3:J6&K3:K6,0))
   ```
2. Then it also concatenates all the values in the columns joined in memory.

   ```
   =INDEX(L3,MATCH("1234",{"1234";"";"";""},0))
   ```
3. And then the actual matching.

Comment: Note you'll need to enter this as a CSE formula (`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`)

Comment: This works but why did you use a range? Like you put J3:J6. If I just leave it as J3 which is where the value is, it does not work. Why is this?

Comment: Also, how would I use this for multiple rows and not just one?

Comment: I figured out how to do it for multiple rows but the instant I do it across multiple worksheets, it fails. Why is this?